# Is it possible to use WPA3 with netplan?

Tags: netplan, wpa3

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and can't connect the wifi using WPA3; I've tried this in **/etc/netplan/01-network.yaml**:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "MYSID":
          password: "mypassword123"
```

It works ok if I setup the router to use WPA2 authentication, but if I set it to WPA3 it fails. What should I do in order to make this work with WPA3?

Please notice that my question is specifically about using **WPA3** with **netplan** using **networkd** as a renderer (solutions using NetworkManager is not what I'm looking for)

Comment: @ArturMeinild the link you suggested does not answer my question ... I'd like to fix this using netplan, no NetworkManager, thanks anyway

Comment: netplan and NetworkManager does not exclude each other - but maybe you mean using netplan with Systemd-networkd as a renderer (which is the other option apart from NetworkManager)?

Comment: As long as `wpa_supplicant` is installed, and your router/AP is set to support WPA3, it should all work.

Comment: @heynnema, wpa_supplicant is installed but it doesn't connect when the router is set to use WPA3

Comment: Yes. I think that if you set the router to WPA2, it'll connect at WPA3 if it can.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/2023238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the networkd backend, netplan dispatches wifi security directly to wpa_supplicant because networkd does not have direct support for this.  Any WPA3 features that are enabled by default in wpa_supplicant are available.  However, if you need to configure WPA3-specific options, such as SAE key management, netplan does not currently support this.  You can file a feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

Comment: Probably the issue is the key management, thank you for the information!